# In C, multithreaded, multiple windows calling one Window Procedure, will each call use new local variables or do I need a mutex?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, user-interface

I tried to explain it all in the title: I have a multithreaded C program which will have multiple windows calling one Window Procedure.

There is some processing done in the window procedure.  Do I need to protect it, or will each call to the window procedure be separated in memory?

My instinct is that I don't need a mutex, because they're all local variables, is this wrong?

```
LRESULT APIENTRY EditSubclassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{   
    if (uMsg == WM_GETDLGCODE) 
        return DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
    else if(uMsg == WM_CHAR)
    {
        if( (int) wParam == 13)
        {
            char* strCurrentCommand;

            unsigned long ulThisConversation = GetConversation(0, 0, hwnd, 0, 0);
            ...
```

I'm concerned with the local variables strCurrentCommand and ulThisConversation.

Comment: Local variables go on the stack. Each thread has its own stack space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables and parameters to functions go on the stack.  Each thread gets its own stack, and each invocation of a function gets a space on the stack of the thread it's running in for its parameters and local variables.  So you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need protect stack variables with mutex.

Answer (score 0):

No need to protect local variables, as each call to the window proc function will allocate new copies on the stack.

But keep in mind that to avoid the need for a mutex or other synchronization mechanisms you also need to make sure any functions called from inside your window proc function (like `GetConversation` and any functions this function calls) are thread safe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  In making a function thread safe, is there anything to consider beyond making sure it doesn't modify globally accessible memory without synchronization?

Comment: Thread safety involves more than just not accessing global memory but just any kind of resources, like files, subprocesses, etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety for a good introduction to thread safety.